# SSH Log In Closes After Password Entry

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sshd

I just bought my first VPS that I got a smoking deal on.

It is running Ubuntu 11.10 X64.

I set up a Minecraft server on it to see how it would handle it, and ending up created a minecraft account on the VPS to run the MC server at boot.

Now I would like to log in to the minecraft through SSH so I can screen the minecraft server. But I am unable to SSH into my VPS using the minecraft account I created. When I enter the account's correct password it immediately closed the SSH session (if I enter the incorrect password it tells me access denied).

I can SSH in with root still.

I have

- made sure the minecraft account has a home folder and appropriate privledges to it.
- edited the sshd_config file, adding a AllowUsers field for minecraft and root
- edited the sshd_config file, setting UsePriviledgeSeparation to no

Answer (score 0):

maybe the user has `/usr/sbin/nologin` ? In any case, make some attempts and then check `/var/log/secure` to see what's wrong.

I belive you can change user login or nologin in `/etc/passwd`